# Why are the ANSI escape chars in this YAML data not being evaluated when output to terminal by my Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, yaml, ansi-escape

I have this YAML data:

*data.yml*

```
game:
  welcome: Welcome to \e[34myour\e[0m new chess game players.\n\n
```

which I am successfully accessing with:

```
puts data['game']['welcome']
```

however when output to terminal neither the ansi escape character formatting nor the newline formatting is working. It just prints out all of the characters literally. I have tried/checked:

- terminal is using UTF-8 encoding and does print ansi escape formatting when directly used on string characters on a ruby programme.
- tried escaping the escape characters with another `\` character, e.g. \e[34myour\e[0m. This doesn't work.

Any ideas how I might be able to get this working? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML only allows escape character sequences in double-quoted scalars. See [section 5.7 *Escaped Characters*](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#57-escaped-characters) of the YAML specification [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> ## 5.7. Escaped Characters
>
> All non-printable characters must be *escaped*. YAML escape sequences use the “`\`” notation common to most modern computer languages. Each escape sequence must be parsed into the appropriate Unicode character. The original escape sequence is a presentation detail and must not be used to convey content information.
>
> Note that escape sequences are ***only interpreted in double-quoted scalars***. In all other scalar styles, ***the “`\`” character has no special meaning*** and ***non-printable characters are not available***.

Comment: Hallelujah @Jorg W Mittag, thank you. Indeed the whole YAML variable value needs to be enclosed in double quotes, so the following works` welcome: "Welcome to \e[34myour\e[0m new chess game players.\n\n"`. Thank you 

Answer (score 0):

Complementing [Jörg W Mittag's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76385847/11942268), if you have a text block and *not* a double quoted scalar, you can work around that by using variables that are double quoted scalars, e. g.:

```yaml
- name: Add a text block with non-printable characters
  vars:
    my_char: "\x04"
  ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
    path: /path/to/file
    block: |
      This is the first line.
      This is the second line with a non-printable character: {{ my_char }}
```